# python logger with threading misbehaving

Tags: python, logging, python-multithreading

I am using python 2.7 to log into a file some messages that are included in threaded calls. However, instead of having the message 1 time, I have the log occurring 3 times . Well, I set a range equals to 5, however, the message is occurring 15 times.

Below is the code :

```
import sys
import logging
import threading  
import logging.handlers
import time 
import os 

ETT="TVAR 1"
objectname="TVAR 2"
URLFORLOG="TVAR 3"

def setup_custom_logger(name):
    fileLogName='visualreclogfile.log'
    #formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - %(message)s')
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    handlerCH = logging.StreamHandler()
    handlerCH.setFormatter(formatter)

    handlerFILE = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fileLogName, maxBytes=(1048576*5), backupCount=7)
    handlerFILE.setFormatter(formatter)


    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger.addHandler(handlerCH)
    logger.addHandler(handlerFILE)

    return logger

def LoggingFileForELK(MessageToBeLogged):
    logger = setup_custom_logger('root')
    logger.info(MessageToBeLogged)


def mainFunction():
    Messages=("*** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : %s WITH NAME KEY : %s HAS URL : %s ") %(ETT,objectname,URLFORLOG)
    MessageToBeLogged=str(Messages)
    LoggingFileForELK(MessageToBeLogged)





threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=mainFunction)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(0.5)
for  t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Below is my result :

```
2017-04-22 12:36:59,010 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:36:59,512 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:36:59,512 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:00,018 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:00,018 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:00,018 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:00,520 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:00,520 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:00,520 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:00,520 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:01,022 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:01,022 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:01,022 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:01,022 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
2017-04-22 12:37:01,022 - INFO - *** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : TVAR 1 WITH NAME KEY : TVAR 2 HAS URL : TVAR 3
```

I looked at this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384065/python-using-logger-with-multiple-handlers) but no answer here.

I cannot see the wrong part code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This duplicating thing actually has nothing to do with `threading`, but rather everything to do with that `for loop` that generates the threads and runs the `mainFunction` with each thread. At each iteration, when you think you are creating a new logger object you are in fact just referencing the same logger object because you are providing the same logger name ('root' in this case). But you are also adding more handlers to this logger object at every iteration. So at iteration `i = 0`, you have 1 logger object, 1 file handler and 1 stream handler. But then when you hit iteration `i = 1`, you now have 1 logger object still, but 2 file handlers (pointing to the same file) and 2 stream handlers. This means that by the end of iteration `i = 1`, you already have 3 lines added to your file and 3 lines printed to your standard stream. Following this incrementing logic, you will end up with 1 logger object, 5 file handlers and 5 stream handlers by the end of the 5th iteration. This, in essence, is what's behind the duplicated rows in your file and in your standard stream.

A fix would be to redefine the `setup_custom_logger` function to only generate new handlers when the logger object does not already exist. Basically, you would have to have some form of container (a dictionary in this case) that tracks the loggers you have created, along with their handlers. If the `setup_custom_logger` gets called with a logger name that already exists, then the function will just return the *existing logger*; but otherwise it generates a new logger with its handlers.

I have tweaked your script to add the fix:

```
import sys
import logging
import threading
import logging.handlers
import time
import os

ETT="TVAR 1"
objectname="TVAR 2"
URLFORLOG="TVAR 3"

# container to keep track of loggers
loggers = {}

def setup_custom_logger(name):
    global loggers
    # return existing logger if it exists
    if name in loggers:
        return loggers.get(name)
    else:   # else, create a new logger with handlers
        fileLogName='visualreclogfile.log'
        #formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - %(message)s')
        formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        handlerCH = logging.StreamHandler()
        handlerCH.setFormatter(formatter)

        handlerFILE = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fileLogName, maxBytes=(1048576*5), backupCount=7)
        handlerFILE.setFormatter(formatter)


        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        logger.addHandler(handlerCH)
        logger.addHandler(handlerFILE)
        loggers[name] = logger
        return logger

def LoggingFileForELK(MessageToBeLogged):
    logger = setup_custom_logger('root')
    logger.info(MessageToBeLogged)


def mainFunction():
    Messages=("*** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : %s WITH NAME KEY : %s HAS URL : %s ") %(ETT,objectname,URLFORLOG)
    MessageToBeLogged=str(Messages)
    LoggingFileForELK(MessageToBeLogged)




threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=mainFunction)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
    time.sleep(0.1)
for  t in threads:
    t.join()
```

#### Edit:

This is normal behavior of loggers and their handles. Even without threading, this will behave the same way as long as you are referencing the same logger and adding handlers to it. The issue here is the `for loop`, not the `threading` process. If you removed the `threading` part from the script, you would still get the duplicated rows. For instance, the following will return the same number of rows as the original threaded version:

```
import sys
import logging
import threading
import logging.handlers
import time
import os

ETT="TVAR 1"
objectname="TVAR 2"
URLFORLOG="TVAR 3"

def setup_custom_logger(name):
    fileLogName='visualreclogfile.log'
    #formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - %(message)s')
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    handlerCH = logging.StreamHandler()
    handlerCH.setFormatter(formatter)

    handlerFILE = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fileLogName, maxBytes=(1048576*5), backupCount=7)
    handlerFILE.setFormatter(formatter)


    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger.addHandler(handlerCH)
    logger.addHandler(handlerFILE)

    return logger

def LoggingFileForELK(MessageToBeLogged):
    logger = setup_custom_logger('root')
    logger.info(MessageToBeLogged)


def mainFunction():
    Messages=("*** CONTENT LOGGING *** OBJECT UUID : %s WITH NAME KEY : %s HAS URL : %s ") %(ETT,objectname,URLFORLOG)
    MessageToBeLogged=str(Messages)
    LoggingFileForELK(MessageToBeLogged)




for i in range(5):
    mainFunction()
```

What this indicates is that it is ***NOT*** the threading that was leading the logging processing to misbehave, but rather the process of adding new handlers to your logger object at every iteration. The bottom line is: `logging` is very much thread aware and will work properly with any threaded application, as long as ***you are not duplicating handlers unnecessarily***. I am not well versed in anything else that does a better job at this than the `logging` module, but there could be greater things out there. I am just not aware of any.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok I get it somehow. Is this a normal behavior of the logger capabilities of python ? Or is there another tool in python that is "thread aware" ?. PS: thanks a lot !